# Inaccurate calculations using double and float

Tags: java, double, floating-point-precision

Why this piece of code is giving inaccurate results?

```
double a = 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3;
System.out.println(a);
float b = 0.3f + 0.3f + 0.3f;
System.out.println(b);
```

Results are

```
0.8999999999999999
0.90000004
```

Comment: Precisions are doubled when you use `double`. You are sacrificing precision when doing the save with float. You should get a compile warning saying that b's precision might be lost or something. Also check out the IEEE floating point number specification when using programming languages and how they are represented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, double values are [IEEE floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Unless they are a power of 2 (or sums of powers of 2, e.g. 1/8 + 1/4 = 3/8), they cannot be represented exactly, even if they have high precision. Some floating point operations will compound the round-off error present in these floating point numbers. In cases you've described above, the floating-point errors have become significant enough to show up in the output.